# A Switch for async function invocations

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have implemented a simple "switch" function - that switches and invokes an alternate function, if the function that is to be invoked fails or timesout.

This code will be later employed as part of circuit breaker.

I request to review the code in general and in particular for correct use of async\await:

```
public class Switch<R>
    {        
        private CancellationTokenSource combinedCancelTokenSource;
        private CancellationToken cancelToken;
        private CancellationToken timeCancelToken;        
        private Func<CancellationToken, Task<R>> alternateFn;
        private Action<Exception> exceptionIntercept;

        public Switch() {
            this.combinedCancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();           
        }

        public async Task<R> InvokeAysnc(Func<CancellationToken, Task<R>> f) {

            bool computeAlternate = false;

            R r = default(R);
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            try {
                watch.Start();
                r = await f(combinedCancelTokenSource.Token);
                watch.Stop();
            } catch(OperationCanceledException) {
                watch.Stop();
                if (timeCancelToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
                    // log as Fault
                    logTimedOut(watch.Elapsed);
                    computeAlternate = true;
                } 
                //else - cancellation was requested by the callee, return default value, do not log as fault                
            } catch(Exception exp) {
                watch.Stop();
                exceptionIntercept?.Invoke(exp);
                logFault(watch.Elapsed, exp);
                computeAlternate = true;
            } 

            if(computeAlternate && alternateFn != null) {
                r = await alternateFn(cancelToken);
            }
            return r;
        }

        private void logFault(TimeSpan elapsed, Exception exp) {
           // will implement later
        }

        private void logTimedOut(TimeSpan elapsed) {
            // will implement later
        }

        public Switch<R> Cancellation(CancellationToken cancelToken) {
            this.cancelToken = cancelToken;
            this.combinedCancelTokenSource = combineTokens(this.cancelToken);
            return this;
        }


        public Switch<R> WithinTime(TimeSpan timespan) {
            CancellationTokenSource timeCancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            timeCancelTokenSource.CancelAfter(timespan);
            this.timeCancelToken = timeCancelTokenSource.Token;

            this.combinedCancelTokenSource = combineTokens(this.timeCancelToken);
            return this;
        }

        public Switch<R> InterceptException(Action<Exception> interceptor) {
            this.exceptionIntercept = interceptor;
            return this;
        }

        public Switch<R> Alternate(Func<CancellationToken,Task<R>> alternateFn) {
            this.alternateFn = alternateFn;
            return this;
        }

        private CancellationTokenSource combineTokens(CancellationToken t) {
            CancellationToken[] tokens;
            if (combinedCancelTokenSource != null) {
                tokens = new CancellationToken[] { combinedCancelTokenSource.Token, t };
            } else {
                tokens = new CancellationToken[] { t };
            }
            return CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(tokens);
        }
    }
```

Unit Tests:

```
[TestClass()]
    public class SwitchTests {

        [TestMethod]
        public void SimpleInvokeTest() {
            Switch<int> c = new Switch<int>();
            int val = 10;

            int x = c.InvokeAysnc((token) => {
                // just to test - wrap the return in a Task run, in real world we would use a async method
                return Task.Run(() => { return val; });
            }).Result;

            Assert.AreEqual<int>(val, x);
        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void OnExceptionAlternateTest() {
            int val = 10;
            int alternate = 5;

            Switch<int> c = new Switch<int>().Alternate((token) => {
                // just to test - wrap the return in a Task run, in real world we would use a async method
                return Task.Run(() => { return alternate; });
            });


            int x = c.InvokeAysnc((token) => {
                // just to test - wrap the return in a Task run, in real world we would use a async method
                return Task.Run(() => {
                    // deleberate divide by zero
                    return val/0; });
            }).Result;

            Assert.AreEqual<int>(alternate, x);
        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void OnExceptionInterceptInvokeTest() {
            int val = 10;
            int alternate = 5;

            Exception exp = null;

            Switch<int> c = new Switch<int>().Alternate((token) => {
                // just to test - wrap the return in a Task run, in real world we would use a async method
                return Task.Run(() => { return alternate; });
            }).InterceptException((e) => {
                exp = e;
            });


            int x = c.InvokeAysnc((token) => {
                // just to test - wrap the return in a Task run, in real world we would use a async method
                return Task.Run(() => {
                    // deleberate divide by zero
                    return val / 0;
                });
            }).Result;

            Assert.AreEqual<int>(alternate, x);
            Assert.IsTrue(exp is DivideByZeroException);
        }



        [TestMethod]
        public void OnTimeoutAlternateTest() {
            int val = 10;
            int alternate = 5;

            Switch<int> c = new Switch<int>().Alternate((token) => {
                // just to test - wrap the return in a Task run, in real world we would use a async method
                return Task.Run(() => { return alternate; });
            }).WithinTime(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 10));


            int x = c.InvokeAysnc((token) => {
                // just to test - wrap the return in a Task run, in real world we would use a async method
                return Task.Run(() => {
                    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
                        if(token.IsCancellationRequested) {
                            throw new TaskCanceledException();
                        }
                        Thread.Sleep(5);
                    }
                    return val;
                });
            }).Result;

            Assert.AreEqual<int>(alternate, x);
        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void OnCalleeCancelDefaultTest() {
            int val = 10;
            int alternate = 5;

            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            cts.CancelAfter(2);

            Switch<int> c = new Switch<int>().Alternate((token) => {
                // just to test - wrap the return in a Task run, in real world we would use a async method
                return Task.Run(() => { return alternate; });
            }).Cancellation(cts.Token);


            int x = c.InvokeAysnc((token) => {
                // just to test - wrap the return in a Task run, in real world we would use a async method
                return Task.Run(() => {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        Thread.Sleep(2);
                        if (token.IsCancellationRequested) {
                            throw new TaskCanceledException();
                        }                        
                    }
                    return val;
                });
            }).Result;

            Assert.AreEqual<int>(default(int),x);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to start a holy war about it but you should know that your bracing style isn't generally the expected style for C#. It is more common for the opening brace to appear on a newline:

```
public int GetFoo()
{
    // ...
}
```

---

According to the [official naming guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx) all methods - `public` or otherwise - should be `PascalCase`

---

Why have you chosen `R` for the Type parameter? It's a small thing, but most people would expect to see `T`. Try to stick with convention where you can.

---

With that small housekeeping aside, here's some example code to highlight an issue with your code:

```
// set up switch
var someSwitch = new Switch<int>()
    .WithinTime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .Alternate(token => Task.FromResult(100));

// do some long work
Thread.Sleep(4000);

// use the switch
var result = await someSwitch.InvokeAsync(token => 
    { 
        Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
        return Task.FromResult(1234);
    });
```

If I've read your code correctly, this will never return because the time based cancellation token will have already requested cancellation and you don't check the `IsCancellationRequested` property at all.

It would be better to store the TimeSpan in a field and set up the time based cancellation token as the first step of your `InvokeAsync` method.

---

Have you thought about how you'd reuse an instance of your switch?

---

I'd also rename your methods so it looks more like:

```
var result = await new Switch<string>()
    .WithTimeLimit(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .WithFallbackFunction(token => Task.FromResult("Fell off a cliff"))
    .RunFunctionAsync(token => Task.FromResult("Hello world"));
```

---

`InvokeAysnc` should be `InvokeAsync`.

Comment: Congrats to reaching 10k btw although I am late to the party.